# Accessing a NSApplicationDelegate method across classes

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In `ApplicationDelegate.h`, I have:

```
@interface appDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

- (IBAction)showPage:(id)sender;
```

In `buttonController`, (which is connected to a button's Send Actions in a Xib) I have another function

```
- (IBAction) clickAction:(id)sender {
  NSLog(@"Clicked");
}
```

I would like to trigger the function with the button with something like:

```
- (IBAction) clickAction:(id)sender {
  [showPage:nil];
  NSLog(@"Clicked and the page is shown");
}
```

What's the correct way to access the `showPage` function across classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the delegate from the current application, then call the method on it.

```
[(appDelegate*)(NSApplication.sharedApplication.delegate) showPage:nil];
```

Comment: no, this is not why the delegate exists. `NSApplicationDelegate` exists to react to system events, not to be used as singleton.

Comment: @vikingosegundo - Fair enough. I suppose what I should have said was that this is a very common use case for the delegate, whether or not it was intended to be used that way.

Answer (score 1):

Don't hard-link the action, just send the action to the first responder.

This is a placeholder object that at runtime will resolve to whoever is the first responder (input field, view, etc.) and via the [chain-of-responsibility pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) searches up the chain until eventually asking your app delegate to respond to the message.

Lean about event handling basics in OS X here:
[Event Architecture](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html)